# Getting Null output while spliting the string in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I am new in selenium javascript. i got null output while splitting the string using this code.

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>var dList = '${StaffAdminEmail}'.split('@'); </td>
    <td>dsplit1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${dsplit1}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>day = '${dsplit1}';</td>
    <td>dsplit2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${dsplit2}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=school_permalink</td>
    <td>${dsplit2}</td>
</tr>
```

where `${StaffAdminEmail} =example@example.com`

Please help me to sort out this issue..

Comment: <tr>
  <td>echo</td>
  <td>javascript{storedVars.variable1.replace('G','a')}</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>

Comment: Thanks Sridhar..Still i got null.I used like this<td>javascript{storedVars.dsplit1.replace('G','a')}</td>

Comment: you have to use split i show example only

Comment: @SridharR got this error [error] Threw an exception: illegal character .when i use  <tr>
    <td>echo</td>
     <td>javascript{storedVars.dList.split('@')[1]}</td> 
    <td>dsplit2</td>
</tr>

Answer (score 0):

I will have to make some assumptions on what you are trying to achieve here.

Taking as you say `${StaffAdminEmail}=example@example.com` and assuming you want to end up with `dsplit1=example` (from before the @) and `dsplit2=example.com` (from after the @). I will not use your variables `dlist` nor `day` because I don't see why you need them.

Now note that javascript function `split(symbol)` will give you an array of strings separated by the symbol (in your case '@'). You can access each individual string in that array by indexing them with [0], [1], etc.

With that, try this to assign the two parts of your `StaffAdminEmail` to `dsplit1` and `dsplit2`, respectively:

> ```
> <tr>
>   <td>storeEval</td>
>   <td>storedVars['StaffAdminEmail'].split('@')[0]; </td>
>   <td>dsplit1</td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td>storeEval</td>
>   <td>storedVars['StaffAdminEmail'].split('@')[1]; </td>
>   <td>dsplit2</td>
> </tr>
> ```

Feel free to ask in comments if I misunderstood what you are trying to achieve or if you need clarification.

(On a side note, since I assume my answer to your previous question was helpful to you, it would be cool if you would accept it as an answer or at least upwote it.)